# Spring Rest API Post command passing null value

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to create a rest post request using Spring but what is been received is a null value.

If I use the first request I get back null values. If I use the second request I receive a 415Unsupported Media Type. Does anyone know where my issue is?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product", method=RequestMethod.POST,produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody Product addProduct(Product p1) {
    System.out.print("Adding product:"+p1.getDescription());
    return p1;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/product2", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Product greeting(@RequestBody Product p1) {
    System.out.print("Adding product:"+p1.getDescription());
    return p1;
   }
```

**UPDATE to include POSTMAN**
1
[image]
2
[image]
3
[image]

Comment: Please, add http request example

Comment: Added HTTP request

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/product")
public ResponseEntity<Product> addProduct(@RequestBody Product p1) {
    System.out.print("Adding product:"+p1.getDescription());
    return new ResponseEntity<Product>(p1, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

By default, Spring should detect that the JSON you are trying to pass can be parsed into a `Product` object. Spring also takes care of the return type, therefore, you don't need to write a lot of code to make the object be parsed back to a JSON.

Also, on Postman, add the header `Content-Type` with the value `application/json`.